Facing problem with angular 17 and firebase
When I tried to add package in my angular 17 application, it can't install the package. it always show this error given below.
ng add @angular/fire
Skipping installation: Package already installed
UPDATE package.json (1169 bytes)
✔ Packages installed successfully.
? What features would you like to setup? Authentication, Firestore
✖ Package install failed.
An unhandled exception occurred: catch clause variable is not an Error instance
See "/tmp/ng-wEb9ns/angular-errors.log" for further details.

how to solve this problem?

It seems like you have @angular/fire already installed in your project. Which version are you using?

"@angular/fire": "^17.1.0",

Try to uninstall it before adding. Also, could you share the logs?

warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the content option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
Initial chunk files | Names         | Raw size
polyfills.js        | polyfills     | 86.27 kB |
styles.css          | styles        |  5.49 kB |
main.js             | main          |  1.24 kB |
                | Initial total | 93.00 kB

Application bundle generation complete. [3.863 seconds]
Watch mode enabled. Watching for file changes...
➜  Local:   http://localhost:4200/
➜  press h + enter to show help

Angular/fire uses firebase-tools internally and here they are trying to setup firebase for you, instead what you can do is setup Firebase directly using the Firebase CLI, make sure to uninstall the angular/fire package and then execute:
npm install -g firebase-tools

Then start the setup by executing:
firebase login

and then add the package angular/fire by doing:
ng add @angular/fire

